Is a passport required to exchange currency in NL?
An unplanned trip to the Netherlands has me without my usual stash of Euros.
Naarden locals indicated to expect that the local banks could not exchange currency (maybe dollars are not available, but obviously Euros are available) and that would have be done in downtown Amsterdam.
I would prefer not to bring my passport downtown, thus the eponymous question:  when is a passport required?

Don't know about the passport question but note that many physical branches of main street banks (ABN AMRO, ING…) have been replaced with ATM and other automated services from Geldmaat. Last time I visited a bank was several years ago but even then they didn't do much besides putting me on the phone with various hotlines so I don't know if you will have much luck with banks. That's possibly one reason why currency exchanges businesses like GWK Travelex seem very common in the Netherlands.

In Germany, I have never had to show my passport to exchange currency. Why would you expect a passport to be required?

For lower amounts, you probably don't need identification. Banks in NL usually don't have cash available anymore, except in the ATM's. Currency exchange is really a challenge. Having said that, most places will accept Mastercard / Visa / Maestro. With Maestro currrently the safest bet although MC / Visa are taking over. A comment because of the uncertainties.

Are there any private exchange offices in Naarden? Why not try them before traveling to downtown Amsterdam? Anyway, why can't you simply use your card or some contactless payment option? (I believe you have one.)

Use ATM to have some cash, but prefer contactless payments. Currency exchange are expensive (and various employees try to scam people), and because Euro (in euro zone) most of them closed (and so also less competition on prices). -- Some office may require passports as additional anti-fraud (not genuine money), some countries requires it to fight tax evasion. And from certain amount "money laundry rules" requires passport check. (money laundry in theory, but they were implemented after 9/11 so the real reason si different).

@Sabine Depends on country. In India, you need a passport to exchange currency (For all legal exchanges). I was asked to provide my Visa also for exchanging currency.

@Sabine as a counterpoint, I've been requested to show my passport to exchange currency at reisebank. (Not that you'd want to exchange currency at reisebank.)

Unfortunately I don't have an answer on your exact question, but given the following:

You are in Naarden
You need euros
You don't want to travel to downtown Amsterdam with your passport

I have two suggestions:

There is a GWK Travelex office in Hilversum. It's still "downtown", but it's closer to Naarden and quieter than Amsterdam. Not sure if this fits, as I don't know the underlying reason that you don't want to travel to downtown Amsterdam with your passport.

As far as I remember, GWK Travelex does not require ID when you just show up and exchange money at the counter. If you place an order though, they certainly do require ID as shown in the last item of this FAQ section ("What do I need to bring...")
You could call ahead to this branch to be sure, or just go there and hope for the best.


I recently learned that you can wire yourself money using Western Union. It requires your passport, but as there is a WU office nearby Naarden in Bussum you don't need to travel downtown A'dam with it. I have not tried this method myself (a friend did), so be cautious with this advice and do some research. For my friend it worked something like this:

They downloaded the Western Union app.
In the app they sent money that could be picked up in cash.
Minutes after the money was sent in the app they went to the WU office, identified themselves and received the money in the local currency.
They were surprised by the low fees and favourable exchange rate.



Again, the WU option is not something I tried myself and I would not be surprised if there were some hidden fees my friend was not aware of. So do check their T&C thoroughly when deciding to use this option.

+1 I just can't believe the OP doesn't have a card. If yes, any ATM fees will be much lower than WU fees.

Yes, the question is unfortunately light on details. FWIW my friend who used this "trick" in Albania said that the WU fees were lower than the ATM fees (this is starting to sound more and more as an ad, sorry). Maybe WU has some promotion for new users? Curious what the OP will do in the end.

@SaaruLindestøkke WU indeed has a promotion for the first transfer, but they can be competitive for repeat customers also if one transfers larger amounts. (Notably competitiveness is only when one does online-initiated transfers.)

@SaaruLindestøkke. I have been using ApplePay.   I have not found a place that does not accept ApplePay.

@gatorback some places allow you to ask for extra cash when paying by digital means (in Dutch its called "bijpinnen", I think it's called cashback in English). Perhaps that's the most economic option to obtain cash?
